# Windows RDP is extremely slow (high GPU load)

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, gpu, high-dpi

I have a problem with accessing my computer using RDP. The frame rate is very slow (about 1-2 fps) and GPU consumption on remote PC is extremely high for GTX 1080:
[image: High GPU consumption]

Absolutely the same effect occurs when I connect from PC to notebook.

When I reboot the remote PC inside RDP session and reconnect, everything becomes fine:
[image: Low GPU consumption]

But after closing RDP and working directly, I have to relog to make DPI scaling work correct. This fix the high DPI issues but triggers high GPU load bug again.

Both computers work under Windows 10 ver 1709. PC has 150% DPI scaling, GTX 1080. Notebook has 100% DPI scaling, decent AMD video card.

P.S. I didn't face the problem until buying a new monitor. Seems this problem is caused by different DPI settings but I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: were you able to resolve this? having exact same issue